# How to profile and address insert/update performance issues?

Tags: sql-server, performance

I am trying to insert thousands of rows into a table and performance is not acceptable.  Rows on a particular table take 300ms per row to insert.

I know that tools exist to profile *queries* run against SQL Server (SQL Server Profile, Database Tuning Advisor), but how would I profile insert and update statements to determine slow running inserts?  Am I forced to use perfmon while the queries run and deduce the issue with counters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first check the query plan of a single insert to understand the costs associated to that operation - it is not known from the question whether the insert is selecting the data from elsewhere.

I would then check the table indexing for the following:

- how many indexes are in place (apart from filtered indexes, each index will be inserted into as well)
- whether a clustered index is present or are we inserting into a heap.
- if the clustered index key means we will be getting a hotspot benefit on the end of the table or causing a large quantity of page splits.

This is all SQL schema based issues, assuming there is no problems within SQL, you can start checking disk IO counters to check for disk queue lengths and response time. Not forgetting the Log drive response time since each insert will be logged.

These kind of problems are very difficult to nail down as any 1 perscriptive thing / silver bullet you can give advice over, just a range of things you should be checking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm betting that the problem is with the selects and not necessarily the updates. Have you tried profiling the select part of the update statement to make sure there isn't a problem there first?